# How to fetch the records from dynamodb from apigateway using mapping template VTL and partiql select statement?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, api-gateway, vtl, partiql

I AM USING VTL TEMPLATE AND PARTIQL TO SELECT THE RECORDS FROM DYNAMODB and testing through POSTMAN.

```
{

"Statement":"SELECT * from "table" where name = ?",
“Parameters”:[
"S": "$input.path('$.name')"]

}
```

From postman I am passing in body and using POST method

```
{
"name":"polly"
}
```

I have used http post method to get from dynamodb via apigateway.
No lambda in between.

I am using http post method to get the names from the dynamodb.

Please chime in if you know how to query from apigateway VTL TO DYNAMODB

Comment: What exception are you getting? `Name` should have the same casing, `{"name":"polly"}`

Comment: I want to know how it will be done through VTL and partiQL statement. I want to read all the records. I am making template in .tpl file which is being used by the response integration method.

Comment: I am getting  blank response in the values of response template when I am using $input.param('$.name')" and sending the name in the body below:
{
"Name":"polly"
}

Comment: I am using response template as below:

#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
    {
        "response": [
          #foreach($elem in $inputRoot) {
                "id": "$elem.id.S",
                "description": "$elem.desc.S",
                "name": "$elem.name.S"
                 }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
        ]
}

Comment: Like I said, I believe the casing of your params should match what you oobtain from the input params.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan IS the query correct to fetch the result based on the name?
{

"Statement":"SELECT * from "table" where name = ?",
“Parameters”:[
"S": "$input.path('$.name')"]

} 

casing are correct at both the places

Comment: But you send in `Name: polly` with a capital N

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan That was mistake while I wrote here. Casing is same.

Comment: Then it looks good.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan, I am getting blank response. :( I am using the post method in the postman as I have given the same in the response integration. and Using the ExecuteStatement method of dynamoDB

Comment: Have you run the same query using the CLI or query editor?